# Global asax rewrite path stopping ajax execution

Tags: jquery, ajax, webforms, global

I am rewriting a URL from my global.asax, to allow for location specific content to be shown.

In global I do this:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (originalPath.Contains("/" + location))
       {
        Context.RewritePath(originalPath.Replace("/" + location, "/frontpage.aspx?location=" + location));
       } 
    }
```

So I pickup the location from the presented URL and then pass it as a parameter in my query string.

My ajax call looks like this:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "frontpage.aspx/GetLinksForGroup",
      data: catId,
```

This call fails each time. I originally thought that this was because I need something like this (Where location is set to value "lib")

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "lib/GetLinksForGroup",
      data: catId,
```

This never completes (it reloads the page and supplies my global with /lib/getlinksforgroup but never fires my web method. I'm guessing because the web method is on my page frontpage.aspx it will never find it..

Can anyone offer any better ways of doing this??

Comment: Hello Bruceiow: I am having same issue with my project looking for help from 1 month, could you please share your solution so i can dig out something. in my project i am trying to call webmethod but not working. here are 2 demo links, ... when you click on second or third text box it will let you edit text and save to database (calling webmethod and saving data). jasbir.bhinderblink.com (**webmethod not working**), bhinderblink.com/users/jasbir/default.aspx (**webmethod is working**). both are calling same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your ajax calls out of redirection.

```
if (originalPath.Contains("/" + location) && !originalPath.Contains("GetLinksForGroup")))
    Context.RewritePath(originalPath.Replace("/" + location, "/frontpage.aspx?location=" + location));
```